# Pandas partial string matching, reverse of contains

Tags: python, string, pandas, lookup

I have two dataframes and I want to do a lookup to add a column of values from one dataframe to the other based on a partial string match.  (In my real case there are multiple columns used for matching up the appropriate rows.)  The first dataframe is:

```
idx   name        age
0     Anne        30
1     Bob         31
2     Chuck       32
```

and the second is

```
idx   sex    comment
0     M      'Bob is great!'
1     F      'Way to go Anne!'
2     M      'Woodchuck'
```

I want to add the age column to the second dataframe at use the value where the comment string contains the employee's name.  That is, find the row(s) of df1 in which the string in the name column is contained in the reference string from df2['comment'].

But this is the **reverse** of the `str.contains()` function.  What I need in this case is an "is in" function like:

```
df2['age'] = df2.apply(lambda row: df1['name'].str.isin(row['comment']), axis=1)
```

but it doesn't seem that Pandas has this.  The end result should look like

```
idx   sex    comment             age
0     M      'Bob is great!'     31
1     F      'Way to go Anne!'   30
2     M      'Woodchuck'         32
```

How can I achieve this reverse lookup of a partial string in a pandas series?

(in case it matters, the actual strings are Japanese characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use str.contains, this would result in something like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#Create the column in the target dataframe
df2['age'] = pd.Series(np.NaN,index=df2.index)

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df2.loc[(df2['comment'].str.contains(row['name'])).fillna(False),'age'] = row['age']
```

This should put all the row in df2 which contain a name in df1 have the corresponding age

To add multiple conditions you can use :

```
mask = (condition1) & (condition2)
df2.loc[mask,'age'] = row['age']
```